# Automatic mount ext4 hard disk on boot problem

Tags: boot, mount, fstab

I used blkid and its output:

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="54221CEE221CD6B8" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda2: LABEL="Data" UUID="FE10555E10551EC9" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda5: UUID="fc63b7f3-9b03-4e85-a0ce-fa638eeff40b" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda6: UUID="f498cfb8-519f-462d-ae26-2fabb709ad8b" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/sdb5: LABEL="backup" UUID="e8572aae-27e7-4d16-84fa-81c437529373" TYPE="ext4"
```

I want to mount sdb5 automatically so I edited  the fstab like this

```
UUID=fc63b7f3-9b03-4e85-a0ce-fa638eeff40b /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
UUID=f498cfb8-519f-462d-ae26-2fabb709ad8b none            swap    sw              0       0
UUID=e8572aae-27e7-4d16-84fa-81c437529373 /media/dongchirua/ ext4 uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=0022,sync,auto,rw 0 0
```

(/media/dongchirua/ is place where I want to mount to)

but when system start, a message shows an error on sdb5 and press S to skip it? Could you please help?

Comment: Hi user 63730, I think you will make it more readable if you place code (and the content of the fstab file), starting each line with 4 spaces, then it will automatically will displayed in the correct layout.

Comment: Hi again user63730, according to this thread http://askubuntu.com/questions/432120/, you managed, is that correct?

Comment: yes, it's my another question, but when I mount after login by using GUI, it is ok. I want to mount automatically at boot

Answer (score 9):

according to [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2081255) thread, when mounting an ext4 partition via fstab, you cannot use `uid=1000,gid=1000`, but permissions should be set in the partition's root directory

Answer (score 1):

Just look at the `dmesg` output

```
EXT4-fs (sdb5): Unrecognized mount option "uid=1000" or missing value
```

good starting options are `defaults`

If you want to tune the drive then you could also add `barrier=0`